# Converting UI from Windows Forms to WPF databinding

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I currently have an application with a user interface in Windows Forms. The code behind this user interface communicates with a service.

For example, I have the following code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private KeyLessAccessLogic ServiceLogic;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceLogic = new KeyLessAccessLogic();
       //LoadValues();
    }

    public KeyLessAccessLogic MyServiceLogic
    {
        get { return ServiceLogic; }
        set
        {
            ServiceLogic = value;
           // RaisePropertyChanged("MyServiceLogic");
        }
    }
    private void BindDataSource()
    {
        cmb_user_name.DataSource = null;
        cmb_user_name.Sorted = false;
        cmb_user_name.DataSource = ServiceLogic.Users;
        cmb_user_name.DisplayMember = "name";
    }
```

And my XAML:

```
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,71,0,0" 
     Name="cmb_user_update" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyServiceLogic.Users}" DisplayMemberPath="name" />
```

Now I recreated the UI in WPF, and I'm a bit lost on the new format. I do believe that example I gave here is one of the examples of the difference between WPF and Windows Forms.

How can I let my application know what the datasource should be of the Dropdown-box `cmb_user_name`? `ServiceLogic` is the central block of my service, accessing for example the database.

As a second thing, I have a listbox to show me some devices. I tried to approach the datasource differently to show what else I have tried:

```
    <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,44,0,0" 
     Name="listBox_detected" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServiceLogic.TheDevicesList}" DisplayMemberPath="name" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XAML` for that:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyServiceLogic.Users}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding User}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="name" />
```

Create a property `ServiceLogic` in your `ViewModel` to hold a `ServiceLogic` object:

```
private ServiceLogic myServiceLogic;
public ServiceLogic MyServiceLogic 
{
    get { return  myServiceLogic; }
    set
        {
            myServiceLogic = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyServiceLogic");
        }
}
```

I assume `Users` is `ObservableCollection`. Or you can create a property which holds `Users` collection directly.

Comment: The problem is that it's in the class `ServiceLogic`, not in the viewmodel itself.

Comment: I updated my question as well. In short I've got a question: since ServiceLogic uses the data from a database, will binding make sure the information is correct? Or should I do a manual refresh when getting data? I mean, getting bound information isn't the same as updating, is it? Maybe you can shed some light on this. I'm trying out the code as well now

Comment: If you **bind** `Users` to a `Control`, any changes made in `Control` should affect on `Users` too, so you don't have to manually refresh data

Comment: @Joetjah however, I don't think `ComboBox` is a good example for that

Comment: @Joetjah you still hasn't provided `KeyLessAccessLogic` structure

Comment: I've found out that I can set my DataContext to KeyLessAccessLogic. With that, your XAML code to get the items (like User) worked and I can now show my data.